# Zend Framework: Router

Tags: zend-framework

That is my two routers:

```
->addRoute('viewTextMaterial', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':mCat/:mCatSub/:mId/:mTitle', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'viewtextmaterial')))
->addRoute('viewNews', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':nCat/:nId/:nTitle/:page', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'viewnews')))
```

In index.phtml file I add this:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('mCat' => 'Test', 'mCatSub' => 'Test', 'mId' => 7, 'mTitle' => 'Test'), 'viewTextMaterial') ?>">Test</a>
```

Exp. for viewnews URL:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('nCat' => News, 'nId' => 5, 'nTitle' => Some title, 'page' => 1), 'viewNews') ?>">some text</a>
```

But why, when I click a href, it redirect me to 'viewnews'?

Comment: Do you really have an `IndexController` with a `viewtextmaterial` and a `viewnews` actions?

Comment: Yes an IndexController I have viewtextmaterial and a viewnews actions.

Comment: Could you give us examples of URLs for `viewTextMaterial` and `viewNews` routes?

Comment: I was just kidding... Usually in MVC land one doesn't even use those names. There is a `TextController`, a `MaterialController` and a `NewsController`, each defining actions like `index()` or `view(id)`. It seems you are coding after an old Zend tutorial. See the one for [Zend v2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

Comment: I don't have problem with viewNews router, only with viewTextMaterial router, but I don't know why. Other my routers work correctly.

Comment: Not having problems doesn't mean that you don't have to review your architecture. When you use something differently than it's supposed to, you eventually break something... Anyway "click on href redirects to viewnews" doesn't mean anything. Paste the value of `href` in the HTML output

Answer (score 1):

In my experience(which is not very great :) )
I think when you use the colon in front of a name, when you are defining a router
i.e like

```
'/:mCat/:mCatSub/:mId/:mTitle',
      array(
           'controller' => 'index', 
           'action'    => 'viewtextmaterial'
            )
```

What you are telling the router to do is to route any url, which follows the above format('/:mCat/:mCatSub/:mId/:mTitle'), to be routed to the controller/action you mentioned there. eg.

**someController/action/x/y**

or

**anoCont/act/a/b**

would  be routed to the same controller/action.

So in your case what you are doing is you are defining two routers with same options(which creates ambiguity), and by default the second defined route is used(Bottom to top matching).

you  can use something like this

```
'/test/:mCatSub/:mId/:mTitle',
          array(
               'controller' => 'index', 
               'action'    => 'viewtextmaterial'
                )
```

so anything that starts with 'test' as controller(in the url) would now be routed to your desired controller/view.

Hope it works.. :) (If it doesn't please enlighten me :) )